# Tensorflow dynamic RNN - Shapes

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Hello dear programmers!

I have multiple frames of a video and I want as many layers in my RNN as I got frames so that I can feed each layer a frame.

notes:
frame shape = 224, 224, 3 (but I flattend it)
number of frames per video = 20 = number of inner layers

At the moment I got this:

```
timesteps = 20
inner_layer_size = 100
output_layer_size = 2

sdev = 0.1

inputs = 224 * 224 * 3

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, timesteps, inputs), name="x")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None), name="y")

# Compute the layers
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=inner_layer_size)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, dtype=tf.float32, inputs=x)

Wz = tf.get_variable(name="Wz", shape=(inner_layer_size, output_layer_size),
                         initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=sdev))
bz = tf.get_variable(name="bz", shape=(1, output_layer_size),
                         initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

logits = tf.matmul(state, Wz) + bz
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

I know that this doesn't do it the way I want it to.
if you look [here](https://hanxiao.github.io/2017/08/16/Why-I-use-raw-rnn-Instead-of-dynamic-rnn-in-Tensorflow-So-Should-You-0/) at the first picture it's clear that the input for each layer is a part of the frame and not a whole one.

My questions now is how I can change that and how I have do adjust my 'Wz' and 'bz' then?
Thanks for taking your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are passing the `state` of the LSTM to the dense layer instead of the `outputs`.

The outputs in your case will be `[None, 68, 100]`. You need to split across `time_steps` and then pass it to the dense layer. This can be achieved with the following code:

```
# LSTM output
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=inner_layer_size)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, dtype=tf.float32, inputs=x)

#Split the outputs across time_steps.
lstm_sequence = tf.split(outputs, tf.ones((timesteps), dtype=tf.int32 ), 1)

#Dense layer to be applied for each time steps.
def dense(inputs, reuse=False):   
   with tf.variable_scope('MLP', reuse=reuse):
      Wz = tf.get_variable(name="Wz", shape=(inner_layer_size, output_layer_size),
                  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=sdev))
      bz = tf.get_variable(name="bz", shape=(1, output_layer_size),
                     initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

      logits = tf.matmul(inputs, Wz) + bz
      prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
      return prediction

# Pass each time step outputs of the LSTM to the dense layer. 
#The layer should have shared weights    
out = []
for i, frame in enumerate(lstm_sequence):
   if i == 0:
      out.append(dense(tf.reshape(frame, [-1, inner_layer_size])))
   else:
      out.append(dense(tf.reshape(frame, [-1, inner_layer_size]),reuse=True))
```

Comment: you have defined `output_layer_size = 4`. so it will be [68, 32, 4]. if your labels are only defined as [32,4] then you take the output of only the last layer out[:, -1, :] , then calculate the loss.